# How can I trash unwanted items in Space Engineers?

Tags: space-engineers

I mine rock, I process rock, I'm left with a few thousand litres of gravel, which is realistic but the stuff has no use.

There appears to  be no "get rid of this" feature so I started just scooping it up in my manual inventory, walking outside, and manually dropping it on the ground.  I figured I'd get an ejector and sorter and just have it automatically spit the gravel out (pollution, yay).

Thing is this, I've been playing for two days now, and the gravel is *still there*.

I'm getting warnings about "too many blocks." Do items dropped EVER go away? If not, how do I prevent my game from crushing itself under the weight of all that gravel without needing to devote resources to cargo bin after cargo bin?

Comment: Apart from making a crap-ton of reactor parts, try turning down the entity/floating block limit in your settings. That might make them despawn.

Comment: It may be prudent to know that connectors can function as more efficient ejectors if one combines a sorter whitelisted to only junk and 'collect all' as well as 'throw out' are both set to on. They drop junk as a singular large boulder instead of many small pebbles.

Comment: @Lexibutt I did this, and now I have a mountain of gravel bricks that I can walk through, but impedes vehicle travel.

Comment: If you are in single player, you can use the admin console to get rid of the floating gravel.
If you don't wanna use that I think the floating entities/blocks disappear when outside a certain range from a player, so you can try some sort of "ejecting system" that will give some push to the entity and send it to an infinite journey into space.